# Setting up multihost SDL Web 8.5 installation

Tags: web8.5, installation

I'm trying to install SDL Web 8.5 on a three hosts environment (DB, SDL CM, SDL CD).
When I install on a single host env (DB, CM and CD on one and the same host) everything works correct - all SDL services are installed and are up.

When I do all the same on different hosts my SDL CM installs and runs but my SDL CD services are installed but not running. Unfortunately my log folder is also not created and I don't know why. So I'm not able to check why the services don't start.

I believe I have valid licenses.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have some details on "installed but not running"? Do you get any errors running the service install powershell/shell scripts? Do you have Java installed?

Comment: Java is installed, env vars are set. In PS I have WARNINGS like:
WARNING: TCP connect to localhost:8082 failed

Then in 60 seconds eror appears:
ERROR: Unable to start service during timeframe of 60s
Please check logs and configuration files.

Comment: Check whether the database port  is open and accessible from CD environment

Comment: The database port is opened and accessible from CD env (checked with telnet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I've found the cause.
On my Windows hosts **JDK 8** was installed instead of **JRE 8**.

For me it sound strange frankly speaking because JDK contains JRE.

Anyway it worked. All I did is that I changed installed version of JAVA from JDK to JRE.

Answer (score 2):

when you look at the microservice bin folders, there is a script to start the microservices manually called start.sh or start.ps1. When you run these manually, you should get errors in the console if there is a problem to start them.

Comment: I'm trying to run 'start.ps1' for Discovery but what I get is only 'SDL*' logo in console and a line below ":: Service Container :: Spring Boot  (v1.4.1.RELEASE) ::".

And nothing else happens in console.

Comment: and when this sdl logo is showing, can you then connect to the service using a webbroser on that machine (eg connect to http://localhost:8082 - or whatever port you configured for the service you are running ?)